# Cannot resume AudioContext in Safari

Tags: safari, web-audio-api

I'm running into an issue where calling `resume` on an `AudioContext` never resolves when attempting to play audio in Safari. I'm creating an `AudioContext` on page load, thus it starts in a suspended state.

[According to this chromium issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=884337), calling `resume` will not resolve if blocked by the browser's autoplay policy. I have a click event bound to a `<button>` that will resume the context if it's suspended. This works in both Firefox and Chrome, and will work in Safari **if** I change the autoplay settings for the site.

Below is how I would normally resume the context:

```
await context.resume();
```

For Safari, I've tried calling resume without waiting for the promise to resolve, and instead register a callback for `onstatechange`, which is then wrapped in a `Promise`:

```
if (window.webkitAudioContext) {
    await new Promise((accept, reject) => {
        this.context.onstatechange = async () => {
            if ((await this.context.state) === "playing") {
                accept();
            } else {
                reject();
            }
         };

        this.context.resume();
    });
}
```

However, nothing has changed: the `Promise` never resolves, which means that the context state isn't changing.

Am I missing something?

Comment: faced the same issue today. promise never resolved

Comment: I'm not sure why the promise returned by `resume()` never resolves but your workaround never resolves because it checks for a wrong value. `state` will be `'running'` when the context was resumed successfully. It also is a regular property which does not need to be awaited. The fourth line would then be `if (this.context.state === "running") {`.

Answer (score 6):

I finally managed to get audio playing on Safari.

The "fix" was rather simple: I had to call `resume` within the event handler that is bound to the element being used to initiate playback. In my scenario, I was using Redux with React, so a dispatch would be made, and resuming the context would happen at a later time within another component. I'm guessing that Safari didn't see this as a direct response to a user interaction event, so it kept the context in a suspended state.

Comment: Thanks, this was a life saver after losing whole day behind this!!

Answer (score 6):

iOS will only allow audioContext to be resumed if it is running within the call-stack of a UI Event Handler. Running it within a Promise moves the call to another call-stack.

Also, `audioContext.resume()` returns a promise, which must be awaited.

Try this:

```
onPlayHandler() {
   alert("State before: " + this.audioContext.state);
   await this.audioContext.resume();
   alert("State after: " + this.audioContext.state);
}
```

Comment: Thank you _so_ much for this. I've spent the last few days reading around the **Web Audio API** and trying (with no small amount of frustration) to iron out the inconsistencies between iOS Safari and every other browser. I made some progress when I learned of the importance of `new AudioContext()` - but the _real_ missing piece of the puzzle was that for iOS Safari, we need to explicitly set the `audioContext.state` from `suspended` to `running` via: `const audioContext = new AudioContext(); audioContext.resume();` Only then will Safari behave like other browsers.